# Can one define "Ramanujan Summation" over algebraic number fields?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, l-functions, divergent-series

With some trepidation, I ask to "evaluate" badly divergent sums.  Generalizing $\sum n = -\tfrac{1}{12}$ what would be the value of this sum over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

$$\sum_{m,n \geq 0} (m+in) \hspace{0.25in}\text{and}\hspace{0.25in}\sum_{0 < m < n } (m+in)$$

This cursory and highly dangerous check shows that we would probably need higher order terms in the Euler McLarurin expansion.

$$  \sum_{m,n \geq 0} (m+in)  = \sum_{m,n \geq 0} m + i \sum_{m,n \geq 0}n 
=  \sum_{n \geq 0} -\tfrac{1}{12} + i \sum_{m \geq 0} -\tfrac{1}{12} = ??? $$

In a sense, all [Ramanujan sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation) do is subtract the sum from an approximating integeral.  I tried:

$$ \sum_{m,n \geq 0}^{M,N} (m+in)  - \int_0^M \int_0^N (x + i y)\,dx \, dy
 = \tfrac{MN(M+N+2)}{2} - \tfrac{MN(M+N)}{2} = \tfrac{MN}{2}$$

This doesn't look right at all, but I did find something called the Khovanskii-Puhlikov theorem which looks like it might give the answer.

---

In general for any number field $K$ and lattice cone $V \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$ in the ring of integers we could try to define:

$$ \sum_{x \in V \subset \mathcal{O}_K} x $$

So I wonder if someone has attempted to define such summations and what they evaluate to.

Comment: Your sum looks like the L-function of a Grössencharakter of $\mathbf{Z}[i]$ evaluated at $s=0$ (but I'm unsure of the details).

Comment: $\sum_{n > 0} 1 = \zeta(0) = -\frac{1}{2}$, so you can set your first sum to be $-\frac{1}{12}(1-\frac{1}{2}) + i(-\frac{1}{12})(1-\frac{1}{2}) = -\frac{1}{24} - i\frac{1}{24}$.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this is exactly what you are looking for, but it seems too related not to mention. You can generalize zeta regularization to any number field $K$, although you run into an open problem.

Over $\mathbb{Q}$ we have the classic (Riemann) zeta regularization $\sum n=\zeta(-1)$, the right hand side of which can be defined by analytic continuation and equals the (in)famous $-1/12$.

Now, for an arbitrary number field $K$, take its Dedekind zeta function, which is also a meromorphic function with a simple pole on 1, and then define the sum over some (see Gerry's comment below) integral ideals of $K$:

$$\sum_{\mathfrak{a}' \in \mathcal{O}_K} \mathfrak{N(a)}=\zeta_K(-1)$$

The exact value of this sum is not know in general. The better understood case is for $K$ totally real, in which it is known to be an rational number (Klingen-Siegel) and conjectured to be related to algebraic K-groups (Birch-Tate).

Comment: When $K$ is not totally real, $\zeta_{K}(-1) = 0$. This is forced by the gamma factors of $\zeta_{K}(s)$, which depend on the number of real and complex embeddings of $K$.

Comment: For the $-1/12$ result, we don't sum over all the integral ideals, nor over all the integers, just over the positive intgers. To get an analogous number for the sum of, say, the Gaussian integers, you'd need to decide which ones you include in the sum.

Comment: @JeremyRouse That's certainly true, but I though there should be extra arithmetic information on the first non-vanishing coefficient of the Taylor expansion. Perhaps I'm mistaken, or you ment something else.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You're obviously right, I didn't think of that. I'm not sure what the convention is, though. I'll leave it unspecified and perhaps someone can fix it later.

Comment: It seems john mangual doesn't want to sum the norms of the ideals of $\mathbf{Z}[i]$, but he would like to sum the generators of these ideals (say in the first quadrant).

Comment: In the case K=Q, the sum of the norms of the ideals boils down exactly to the sum over positive integers.